# Using a joint distribution table to find probability?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

I have the following joint distribution table.

[image]

I am trying to answer the following questions. A,B,C,D

For

(a) I put $P(X=1, Y=2)=1/20$

(B) $p(x=0,1\le y<3)= 1/4+1/8$

But I am not sure how to do $c$ and $d$.

Comment: $(X,Y)$ can take on $9$ possible values. Make a list of them. Then for each of the $9$ cases, check whether $X+Y$ is at most $1$, and make a sub-list. Then admire the sub-list and think of the third axiom of probability.

Comment: You should not be using capital $P$ and lower-case $p$ interchangeably, nor capital $X$ and lower case $x$ nor capital $Y$ and lower-case $y$.  This distinction makes it possible to understand things like $P(W=w) = cw^2$, etc. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just summing those items that satisfy the condition.

$P(X+Y\le 1)= P(X=0,Y=0)+P(X=0,Y=1)+P(X=1,Y=0)=\frac{1}{12} + \frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{6}$

Similarly:

$P(X>Y)=\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{24}+\frac{1}{40}$

Comment: Oh I see you can have at most 3 object chosen.

Comment: @Fernando Martinez: The "at most 3" is a coincidence.  Each of (c) and (d) involve drawing a suitable diagonal line across the table and adding up all the probabilities on the relevant side of line.